# cambiar elementos de una lista python

Tags: python, lista

quiero que la siguiente función cambie los 0 por 1 y los 1 por 0, intenté separar el número por elementos, lo cuál logré hacer, pero no logro cambiar los digitos
hasta ahora lo que llevo es esto

```
def complementoa1(num1):
    x=[int(a) for a in str(num1)]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if num1==1:
            num1=0
        else:
            if num1==1:
                num1=0
            return num1


print(complementoa1(1010101010))
```

Comment: Basta con `return [int(not int(a)) for a in str(num1)]`

Comment: me podrías explicar un poco más tu respuesta porfavor?

Comment: ahora redacto una respuesta

Comment: En mi opinión, las 3 respuestas dadas están mal, ya que tal como está escrito el código, se trata de interpretar un valor numérico en base 10 como si fuera un valor binario. El [complemento a uno](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_a_uno) es una operación que se realiza a nivel de bit. Aunque el valor recibido y el devuelto parecen ser valores binarios, no lo son y el valor devuelto no es ni remotamente el complemento a uno del valor recibido, ya que no son valores en base 2 sino en base 10.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes muchas cosas mal en tu código. Para empezar en el ciclo `for` haces la siguiente comparación `num1 == 1`. Esto está mal pues `num1` es el parámetro que recibes que es un número largo y lo comparas solo con un dígito y est ocurre en ambas condiciones, por lo Lo que nunca se cumplirá ninguna. Lo que deberías hacer es comparar cada dígito del número para saber si es `1` o `0`, por algo haces el ciclo `for`. Lo "correcto" sería hacer esto `if num1[x]`, pero dará error ya que `num1` es un entero y con los enteros no puedes usar la notación de corchetes. Antes que nada deberías hacer esto `num1 = str(num1)` con eso ya conviertes el parámetro en un string.

Otro error es hacer esto `num1 = 0` con eso lo que haces es sobreescribir el valor que recibes por parámetro, ahora en vez de ser un número largo de 0s y 1s es solo un 0. Si deseas reemplazar un elemento de una lista debes acceder a este y asignarle un nuevo valor. Ejemplo:

```py
objeto[indice] = valor
#objeto debe ser subscriptable o implementar los métodos getitem y setitem
```

Esta es la única forma de modificar los elementos de una lista.

Al ver que utilizas una *list comprehesion* para tener una lista de números, quizá quisiste hacer esto:

```py
def complementoa1(num1):
    nums = [int(a) for a in str(num1)]
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 1:
            nums[i] = 0
        elif nums[i] == 1:
            nums[i] = 0
    return num1
```

Lo que dije en mi comentario es algo mucho más simplificado. Tomando que el `0` es representado como `False` y el `1`como `True` y viceversa, entonces si negamos cada uno de estos obtenemos su inverso. Este concepto es lo que utilizo en mi código.

```py
def complementoa1(num1):
    return [int(not int(a)) for a in str(num1)]
```

Como `a` tomará el valor de cada dígito del string entonces lo primero que hacemos es convertirlo a entero, por eso hago `int(a)`. Luego, como dije, negamos ese número con `not int(a)`; sin embargo esto nos retornará un valor booleano. Tomando nuevamente lo que dije, si convertimos un booleano a entero nos dará `0` si es `False` y `1` si es `True`. Esa es la magia de todo mi código. Finalmente retornamos la lista y nada más.

Recuerda que esto retornará una lista y no un entero ni un string, recomendaría que se retornara un sting ya que en caso haya un `0` al inicio este será ignorado como entero, pero siendo string no, a menos que eso quieras.

Answer (score 0):

El desarrollado la función con una lógica distinta y usando el método de reemplazar caracteres.

```
def complementoa1(numero):
   #Convertimos el número a cadena
   strNumero = str(numero)

   #Como es cambiar '1' por '0' y viceversa
   #No se puede hacer directamente sin causar conflicto
   #Cambiamos por ejemplo los '1' por un caracter cualquiera 'a'
   Complemento = strNumero.replace('1','a')
   
   #Ahora los '0' por '1'
   Complemento = Complemento.replace('0','1')

   #Por {ultimo el caracter aletario que escogimos, 'a', por '0'
   Complemento = Complemento.replace('a','0')

   #Recomiendo retornar la cadena porque si lo conviertes a número
   #y hay un 0 delante, este desaparecerá
   return Complemento


#Imprimimos una prueba de la función
print(complementoa1(1010101010))
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí otra lógica para desarrollar el problema planteado, esta vez con bucles y recorriendo la cadena inicial caracter por caracter.

```
def complementoa1(numero):
#Convertimos el número a cadena de caracteres
strNumero = str(numero)

#Creamos una cadena donde llenaremos el complemento, al inicoo está vacía
#En python puedes usar '' o "" para representar cadenas
#En otros lenguajes se usa '' para caracteres y "" para cadenas, como dato extra
Complemento = ""

#Con este bucle for, recorreremos la cadena de caracteres(como un array)
#Esta declaración de for dice que se crea una variable digito
#y que esta será cada posición de la cadena de caracteres(como un array)
for digito in strNumero:
    
    #Para cada digito o caracter hará la comparación con el digito '0'
    if(digito=='0'):
        
        #Si es igual entonces a la cadena Complemento le agregará un '1'
        Complemento+='1'
        
    else:
        #De lo contrario(se asume que solo se ingresan núemros de '1' y '0')
        #Si el digito o caracter no es '0' entonces es '1' y por ello se
        #agrega un '0' a la cadena complemento
        Complemento+='0'
#Finalmente, retornamos el complemento que no es más que la cadena que hemos
#formado luego de hacer un recorrido completo a la cadena inicial
return Complemento

#Probamos e imprimimos la pruebita
print(1010101010)
print(complementoa1(1010101010))
```